# D3 Polyline and text overlapping

Tags: d3.js

I want to implement polyline for Pie chart in d3 v4 version which should not overlap, they should automatically adjust. I have searched and tried many but they are not useful.

can anyone help me through this, thanks in advance

I have tried this, when the data values are increased they are overlapped.

https://bl.ocks.org/laxmikanta415/dc33fe11344bf5568918ba690743e06f

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>

/* Add shadow effect to chart. If you don't like it, get rid of it. */
svg {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3) );
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25) );
}

/*Styling for the lines connecting the labels to the slices*/
polyline{
    opacity: .3;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}

/* Make the percentage on the text labels bold*/
.labelName tspan {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* In biology we generally italicise species names. */
.labelName {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-style: italic;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body> 
  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
   
   
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)
      .append("g");
    
    svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "slices");
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "labels");
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "lines");
    var width = 500;
    var height = 400;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
    var data = [26,25,10,3000,30,50,33,56,38];
    
    
    
    var pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(d => d);
    var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(radius*0.8).outerRadius(radius*0.6);
    
     var outerArc = d3.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)
                .innerRadius(radius * 0.9);
     
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    
    svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append('path')
   .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d,i)=> color(i));
    svg.append('g').classed('labels',true);
    svg.append('g').classed('lines',true);
     

     var polyline = svg.select('.lines')
                .selectAll('polyline')
                .data(pie(data))
              .enter().append('polyline')
                .attr('points', function(d) {
  
                    // see label transform function for explanations of these three lines.
                    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
                    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos]
                });
        
     
 
       var label = svg.select('.labels').selectAll('text')
                .data(pie(data))
              .enter().append('text')
                .attr('dy', '.35em')
                .html(function(d) {
                    return d.data;
                })
                .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
                    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
                })
                .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
                    return (midAngle(d)) < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end';
                });
    
     svg.append('text')
                        .attr('class', 'toolCircle')
                        .attr('dy', -15) // hard-coded. can adjust this to adjust text vertical alignment in tooltip
                        .html('sdfsd') // add text to the circle.
                        .style('font-size', '.9em')
                        .style('text-anchor', 'middle');
    
    function midAngle(d) { return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2; } 
    
    
  </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Pie charts may not be the best way of representing this data. Data visualization does depend on the scale of the data you are viewing.

Comment: Thanks @Coola for the response. 
Yes, the scale of the data varies. But it is the requirement to show in Pie chart, but can not fix the poly lines